# Preload css in angular 15

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-ssr

I'm crating application in angular with SSR

How do I apply `<link rel="preload" href="/styles.css" as="style" />` to head section or `Link` header in order to preload/prefetch whole styles.css file?

Using plain `styles.css` is not enoug as production build generate file that contains random characters like `styles.7541caaaab536370.css` (different in every build)

Googling about preloading and prefetching in angular only results in preloading components/modules and I'm out of ideas

Comment: It is `rel="preload"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload

Comment: @E.Maggini well, good point, yes, but it does not help with my question

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by preloading the CSS in that way?

Comment: If the file is dynamic how is it loaded now

Comment: @PaulThorsen, main point is to minimize TBT

Comment: You won't be able to decrease your TBT by preloading the CSS. With SSR, the entire application is rendered on the server and then sent to the client. Bundled into this initial HTML is a bunch of inlined CSS. You can see this by viewing the page source of your application. You'll see a <style> tag with all the CSS needed by the current page. FCP is minimized with SSR because it ships down HTML that is view-ready. TTI is slow because the application has to bootstrap to the client after the initial HTML is received. TBT is relatively similar whether you do SSR or CSR.

Comment: @PaulThorsen There is an options in `angular.json` in build optimization that regulates if it should generate inline style called `inlineCritical`. This option is disabled in my project as there is a lot of css that should be critical but for some reason isn't and when `inlineCritical` is enabled then CLS goes through the roof. Preloading will help with TBT as it tells browser to load given file (styles.css in my example) before brwwser discovers it itself and stops rendering in order to fetch this file.

Comment: I see - thanks for the info. Have you considered placing your styles.css in the assets folder? That way, the output file will not be "fingerprinted" and you'll have the ability to reference it directly from your index.html as it will simple be named styles.css post-build.

Comment: @PaulThorsen after some testing this will not work unfortunately. main css file is combined with css from other modules and still generates `styles.<sth>.css`

Comment: I'm able to achieve the desired result in testing it. What do you mean that it the main css file is combined with css from other modules? Your styles.css is pulling in other CSS? Or other angular components are pulling in the styles.css?

Answer (score 2):

You can include the `styles.css` file in the assets folder. This will prevent the angular build process from "fingerprinting" the file and the resulting build file will simply be named `styles.css` allowing you to reference it directly from your `index.html`.